# when converting an integer value to string the string comparison fails, and returns false boolean value

Tags: java, string, integer

```
public class run
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        boolean b;
        int i=3;
        b=Integer.toString(i)=="3";
        System.out.println(b);

    }
}
```

according to my code it should return true,but outputting false.

Comment: Use `.equals` instead of `==`

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot I understand the use of == and equals.
I wanted to understand in what all cases repetitive String is taken from the String pool?
just as "abc" == "abc" returns true. why not this.

Answer (score 1):

Youre using `==` when you should use:

```
b=Integer.toString(i).equals("3");
```

I don't know  why you use `x`. I'm assuming a typo.

Basically the `==` compares the reference used by the literal's being compiled in to the reference to a new string object created from an integer that, due to implementation details, **may or may not have been interned**.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class run
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        boolean b;
        int i=3;
        x=Integer.toString(i).equals.("3");  // change in this line
        System.out.println(x);

    }
}
```

== compares the reference of object while equals method comapres the value.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use `equals` instead of `==` for comparing `String`.  [Here's a good explanation as to why.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767379/61624)
2. You should get into the habit of writing `equals` like this:

   ```
   x= "3".equals(Integer.toString(i));
   ```

   Notice how the literal value is on the left hand side and not the right hand side like all these other answers.  The benefit here is this avoids a possible null pointer exception if the value passed into `equals()` is a null.  `"3"` can never be null.  If you wrote your code like the other answers, to be as safe as possible, you'd have to add extra lines like this:

   ```
   String s = ...
   x = s != null && s.equals("3");
   ```

   It's less work to write it like this:

   ```
   String s = ...
   x = "3".equals(s);
   ```

Comment: Note that `Integer.toString(i)` will never return `null`.

Comment: @arshajii This is factually correct, but it's still good to get into the *habit* of writing `equals()` like this